# PHP Toggle switch with update database

Tags: php, html

I want to make an **toggle** switch with **active / inactive**.

So when the button is inactive it will set an PDO query `"UPDATE users SET user_active = 1"`

Same with active to inactive switch to 0.

My code so far:

```
<?php
   if ($r['user_active'] == 1){
      echo '<input checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Actief" data-off="Inactief" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" type="checkbox">';
   } else{
      echo '<input data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Actief" data-off="Inactief" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" type="checkbox">';
   }
?>
```

Comment: and your question is???

Comment: If someone could give me an quick example how to make a toggle switch with active / inactive with the action of an update query

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code is rendering funny, but when working with HTML, you might find it easier if you used [Alternative Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). Take a look at the docs I linked, you might find them helpful.

```html
<?php if ($r['user_active'] == 1) : ?>
  <input checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Actief" data-off="Inactief" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" type="checkbox">
<?php else : ?>
  <input data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Actief" data-off="Inactief" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" type="checkbox">
<?php endif; ?>
```